# What does the SVD of the numerical derivative matrix of paired instances tell us about our data?

Tags: matrix, svd, derivative

Let's say we have real-valued random variables $X$ and $Y$, and that under simple random sampling we obtain paired values $\{(x_1,y_1), \cdots, (x_i,y_i), \cdots, (x_m,y_m) \}$.

From this sample we can define a matrix

$$\mathbf{Q}_{m \times m} = (q_{i,j}) \triangleq \begin{cases} \frac{y_i - y_j}{x_i - x_j} & x_i \neq x_j \\ 0 & x_i = x_j\end{cases}$$

that encodes a numerical derivatives of how one variable changes with respect to another across instances.

We can then consider the singular value decomposition of $\mathbf{Q}$:

$$\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{U}\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{V}^T$$

which contains unitary matrices $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ along with the diagonal matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ containing our singular values.

I don't have a particular use case for this in mind yet, however exploratory data analysis is a potentially fruitful approach. One way to visualize parts of this decomposition is to examine a [biplot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biplot) of the first couple of components. Perhaps seeing groupings of points coloured by some factor might be interesting.

**Question**: What does the singular value decomposition of this matrix potentially tell us about the data (if anything)?

Comment: I'm open to suggestions on how to narrow the scope of this question if it is too broad.

Comment: Interesting.If Q represents sensitivity matrix. Assuming SVD would be used for PCA, then principal components might tell about variable importance.

Comment: @MehmetSüzen Is $\mathbf{Q}$ a sensitivity matrix? What is a sensitivity matrix?

Comment: I don't think it says much at all without additional assumptions.  I am concerned about the potentially extreme bias introduced by neglecting the cases where $x_i=x_j.$

Comment: @whuber Three options come to mind for assigning values to $q_{i=j}$. One is  $q_{i=j} := 0$, another is  $q_{i=j} := 1$, and the third is  $q_{i=j} := y_i - y_j$. Such choices certainly influence what the resulting matrix represents.

Comment: @whuber A notion of bias makes sense only after we have established that something is being estimated and that the expectation of the estimates across samples does not equal the estimand. It is too soon to call it bias because we don't know what it is.

Comment: @whuber What types of assumptions come to mind?

Comment: That's precisely the problem I have with this post: it isn't even a well-formulated statistical question yet.  It's of the form "if I do this mathematical operation, is there any way I can discover a meaning in it?"  That just doesn't work here.  I'm not saying it's wrong to think about such things, only that certain kinds of questions and discussions are just not on topic on CV.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your exacting feedback.

Comment: I confess it's even an *interesting* question.  I wish we could find a way to fit it into the SE framework.